# Check if letter x is between two quotes

Tags: java

I'd like to check if some character is between 2 other chars.

For example, given the following String:

```
String myString = "Hello, my name is 'Tesda', and this is 'ASDfs'."
```

I want to check if the `'S'` in `"ASDfs"` is between `''` or not, also keeping in mind I want to check every `''`, not jump directly to the second `''`.

I've tried a silly code (I'm not familiar with this at all, as I didn't need it until now), which is:

```
boolean isBetween;

if (!MyString.substring(MyString.indexOf("'"), MyString.indexOf("'")).contains("S"))
    isBetween = true;
```

Well, this didn't work and I don't understand how to make it perfectly.

Also, I want to replace that S with another letter, but I want only between the `''`, not the one after `"my name is"`, I thought about getting the index of the letter, if it's inside `''`, then replace that letter in that specific index, is that possible?

Using the provided answer, I've made the following code ( which why i posted this question for ) :

```
String NewText = "Hello, My NAme is 'Ba', i'm from 'LA' ";
boolean contains = false;
int indexOfS = -1;

String MyString_temp = NewText;

while (MyString_temp.length() >= 0) {
int first = MyString_temp.indexOf("\'");
if(first == -1)
  {
     break;
  }
int second = MyString_temp.substring((first + 1)).indexOf("\'");
second = second + first + 1;
     if(second == -1)
          {
       break;
          }
contains = MyString_temp.substring(first,second).contains("A");
    if (contains) {
      break;
       }
MyString_temp = MyString_temp.substring((second + 1));
}

Log.i("ResultTest","Index is: " + indexOfS + " - Text is: " + MyString_temp);


if(!contains){
Log.i("ResultTest", "Yes " + i);
Log.i("ResultTest","TeF: " +NewText.replace(NewText.substring(indexOfS,indexOfS+1),"Test"));
} else
Log.i("ResultTest", "No " + i);
```

Output

```
Index is: -1 - the text here ..
Failed to output, invalid index
```

Comment: You should consider using `regex`...

Comment: I'd love to, but i don't know how, you have any example/link please ?

Comment: have you looked at regex?

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: @brso05 where's the related part to the question ?

Comment: you could use split("<your_character>" ) and check all all the elements but the first and last

Comment: @AboHani that is a tutorial for learning `regex`...If you have problems trying to implement a solution to your problem please come back and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [regular expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm). Your example could be as simple as

```
MyString.matches("\'S\'");
```

**EDIT:** Updated answer for updated question: Your initial code block looked like it might have done the trick, however you must remember that `indexOf()` only returns the first occurence of what you need. This could work:

```
String MyString_temp = MyString;
String lookingFor = "S";
String separator = "\'";

boolean contains = false;
int indexOfLooking = -1;

while (MyString_temp.length() >= 0) {
   int first = MyString_temp.indexOf(separator);
   if(first == -1) {
       break;
   }
   int second = MyString_temp.substring(first + 1).indexOf(separator);
   second += first + 1;
   if(second == -1) {
       break;
   }
   indexOfLooking = MyString_temp.substring(first, second).indexOf(lookingFor);
   contains = (indexOfLooking >= 0)
   if (contains) {
      break;
   }
   MyString_temp = MyString_temp.substring(second + 1);
}
```

After the `while` loop, `contains` has your answer, and `indexOfLooking` has the location of `S`.

Comment: Consider this scenario `lkkjljk 'lkjlj' *****s****** 'lkjlkj'.` That will match because there is an `s` between the first occurrence of `'` and the last occurrence of`'`. I don't think that is the desired result. You might want a non-greedy expression...

Comment: exactly what i was thinking about, would the spilt method by @hasan work ?

Comment: @AboHani I updated my answer, would that work for you?

Comment: @AboHani actually using `split()` might be a lot easier in this case. It might be tough to build the correct `regex` expression...

Comment: The index is returning -1 .

Comment: @AboHani fixed now

Comment: Thanks a lot, one final question please, using your code i've known the index of between `'letter'` and changed it inside it, is there a way to know the index of every "S" outside '' ? like the opposite of this code.

Comment: @AboHani You could use a loop to find the indices of all `S`'s, store that in a `Hashset`,  then remove the index of `S` inside

Answer (score 0):

With Apache Commons you can use the following method:

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "'");
```

to get an String[] with all results use this:

```
StringUtils.substringsBetween(str, "'", "'");
```